# Leaving one item out in a python list and print paths

Tags: python, string

Given a large number of research subjects ("SUBJ"), I need to create blocks of absolute paths (as strings) that leave one subject out each time.

For example, I need something like:

/path/to/data/SUBJ02 
/path/to/data/SUBJ03 
/path/to/data/SUBJ04 
/path/to/data/SUBJ05

/path/to/data/SUBJ01 
/path/to/data/SUBJ03 
/path/to/data/SUBJ04 
/path/to/data/SUBJ05 

etc...

Given:

```
x = ["SUBJ01","SUBJ02","SUBJ03","SUBJ04","SUBJ05"]
loso = ["SUBJ01","SUBJ02","SUBJ03","SUBJ04","SUBJ05"]

def returnLoso(x,loso):
     x1 = [(z) for (z) in x if z !=loso]
     print x1
```

The result in my interactive session is something like this:

```
In [1]: for i, v in enumerate(loso):
   .....:     returnLoso(x,v)
   .....:     
['SUBJ02', 'SUBJ03', 'SUBJ04', 'SUBJ05']
['SUBJ01', 'SUBJ03', 'SUBJ04', 'SUBJ05']
['SUBJ01', 'SUBJ02', 'SUBJ04', 'SUBJ05']
['SUBJ01', 'SUBJ02', 'SUBJ03', 'SUBJ05']
['SUBJ01', 'SUBJ02', 'SUBJ03', 'SUBJ04']
```

So far, so good.

My question is, how can I plug these into my file paths, to get the result like the one above? I need to plug each "position" in the array into a stand-alone text string. Thanks in advance,

Comment: They are called *lists*, not *arrays*, in Python.

Comment: thx Jakob wasn't sure if appropriate if *I* say that ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what about

```
directory = "c:\\..."
import os.path
paths = [os.path.join(directory, filename) for filename in filenames]
```

?

Btw you can save the repetitions of your subject names by a function like

```
def loo(x):
    return [[el for el in x if el!=x[i]] for i in range(len(x))]
```

Update ok everything together:

```
import os.path

def loo(x):
    return [[el for el in x if el!=x[i]] for i in range(len(x))]

def p(subjects, directory):
    l = loo(subjects)
    for group in l:
        for subj in group:
            print os.path.join(directory, subj)
        print

p(['S1','S2','S3','S4','S5'], 'c:\\')
```

Try running that, results in

```
c:\S2
c:\S3
c:\S4
c:\S5

c:\S1
c:\S3
c:\S4
c:\S5

c:\S1
c:\S2
c:\S4
c:\S5

c:\S1
c:\S2
c:\S3
c:\S5

c:\S1
c:\S2
c:\S3
c:\S4
```

Comment: So, since you got the answer you like, give some props and check the check mark next to that answer